# How to get 2 different objects to react to the same function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make double doors for this css art project I'm doing but i can't get the function right, I'm trying to make it so that when you hover over the button, the doors crack a bit but only one door is cracking. please help.

```js
function crackShipDoors(){
 var door1 = document.getElementById('door').style.left = "37.2%";
 var door2 = document.getElementById('door2').style.left = "52.2";
 
 
}
function closeShipDoors(){
 var door1 = document.getElementById('door').style.left = "37.9%";
 var door2 = document.getElementById('door2').style.left = "50.3";

}
```

```css
#door{
 width:12.4%;
 height:43.4%;
 position:absolute;
 left:37.9%;
 top:25.5%;
 background-color:#666666;
 border:thin black solid;
 transition: 1s;
 z-index:-6;
}
#door2{
 width:12.4%;
 height:43.4%;
 position:absolute;
 left:50.3%;
 top:25.5%;
 background-color:#666666;
 border:thin black solid;
 transition: 1s;
 z-index:-6;

}
#openbutton{
 width:30px;
 height:20px;
 position:absolute;
 left:64%;
 top:40%;
 background-color:#00FF00;
 transition: 1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#openbutton:hover{
 opacity:.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door2"></div>
  <div id="openbutton" onmouseover="crackShipDoors()" onmouseout="closeShipDoors()"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'cracking'? It looks okay to me from what I can understand from your question. https://jsfiddle.net/8arpbxw0/

Comment: You're missing the `%` on the `#door2` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were simply missing a couple percentage signs in your javascript.

```js
function crackShipDoors(){
 var door1 = document.getElementById('door').style.left = "37.2%";
 var door2 = document.getElementById('door2').style.left = "52.2%";
 
 
}
function closeShipDoors(){
 var door1 = document.getElementById('door').style.left = "37.9%";
 var door2 = document.getElementById('door2').style.left = "50.3%";

}
```

```css
#door{
 width:12.4%;
 height:43.4%;
 position:absolute;
 left:37.9%;
 top:25.5%;
 background-color:#666666;
 border:thin black solid;
 transition: 1s;
 z-index:-6;
}
#door2{
 width:12.4%;
 height:43.4%;
 position:absolute;
 left:50.3%;
 top:25.5%;
 background-color:#666666;
 border:thin black solid;
 transition: 1s;
 z-index:-6;

}
#openbutton{
 width:30px;
 height:20px;
 position:absolute;
 left:64%;
 top:40%;
 background-color:#00FF00;
 transition: 1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#openbutton:hover{
 opacity:.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door2"></div>
  <div id="openbutton" onmouseover="crackShipDoors()" onmouseout="closeShipDoors()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `%` symbols from `door2`:

```js
function crackShipDoors(){
 var door1 = document.getElementById('door').style.left = "37.2%";
 var door2 = document.getElementById('door2').style.left = "52.2%";
 
 
}
function closeShipDoors(){
 var door1 = document.getElementById('door').style.left = "37.9%";
 var door2 = document.getElementById('door2').style.left = "50.3%";

}
```

```css
#door{
 width:12.4%;
 height:43.4%;
 position:absolute;
 left:37.9%;
 top:25.5%;
 background-color:#666666;
 border:thin black solid;
 transition: 1s;
 z-index:-6;
}
#door2{
 width:12.4%;
 height:43.4%;
 position:absolute;
 left:50.3%;
 top:25.5%;
 background-color:#666666;
 border:thin black solid;
 transition: 1s;
 z-index:-6;

}
#openbutton{
 width:30px;
 height:20px;
 position:absolute;
 left:64%;
 top:40%;
 background-color:#00FF00;
 transition: 1s;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#openbutton:hover{
 opacity:.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door2"></div>
  <div id="openbutton" onmouseover="crackShipDoors()" onmouseout="closeShipDoors()"></div>
```